# Rails API render associated objects name instead of id in form of JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I'm trying to implement Rails API, and I have following two models:

1. Event

   ```
   belongs_to :location   accepts_nested_attributes_for :location
   ```
2. Location

   ```
   has_many :events
   ```

with

```
event = Event.all
```

I'm getting `location_id` with other data but I want to show `location.name` instead of `location_id` for API request to index path i.e
`localhost:3000/api/events`.

Currently i m getting response as

```
[{"id":5,"name":"event420","description":"22","venue":"","contact":"","cost":"","created_at":"2015-07-01T05:49:22.738Z","updated_at":"2015-07-01T05:49:22.738Z","started_at":"2015-07-01T06:00:00.000Z","ended_at":"2015-07-01T06:30:00.000Z","owner_id":6,"city_id":null,"slug":"event420","clot_id":null,"location_id":10}]
```

instead of location_id: 10 i want Location.name

Please suggest me, how i can do that.

Comment: Where do you want to show `location.name` instead of `location_id`?

Comment: If your are asking about the routes to be contains the name of the location instead of the id then there is a gem called friendly-id that will solve your problmes.

Comment: Do you have any relation between the events and location ?

Comment: Try to add a json view for your request and add the attributes which you needs only.

Comment: @Adt Can you please post your complete controller's code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def index
    @events = Event.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render :json => @events.to_json(:include => { :location => { :only => :name } }) }
    end
end
```

Add this code to events_controller

Comment: ActionController::UnknownFormat

Comment: `Started GET "/api/events" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-01 16:38:45 +0530
Processing by API::EventsController#index as HTML` This says that your request is HTML request and that is why you are getting this error..for above code to work you need to send your request as js